# How to create custom 403 error page in magento2

Tags: magento2, error, magento-2.2.5, page-layouts, theme-overriding

How can I create a custom error pages in my **Magento 2** site. For example this pages: `500, 401, 403, and 404`.

I tried for create block:

```
 $layout = $this->_view->getLayout();
 $block = $layout->createBlock('Training\Test\Block\Test');
 $this->getResponse()->appendBody($block->toHtml());
```

But not working return error

> Catalog Layer has been already created

Below is my Controller

```
    class View{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->toolbar = $toolbar;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function beforeExecute(\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View $category)
    {

        $product_limit = $category->getRequest()->getParam('product_list_limit');
        $available_limits = $this->toolbar->getAvailableLimit();
        if(!in_array($product_limit, $available_limits) && !empty($product_limit)) 
        {
            /*$norouteUrl = $this->url->getUrl('noroute');
            $category->getResponse()->setRedirect($norouteUrl);
            return;*/
            return $this->resultForwardFactory->create()->forward('noroute');
        }
    }
}
```

In that I want to replace return `$this->resultForwardFactory->create()->forward('noroute');` with my custom error page URL

Comment: Can you add your all codes like xml, controller and block files?

Comment: I get an error when editing a customer address. When I enter it into the system, when I save it, I get an error message "The requested URL has been rejected. For more information, please contact support and provide this reference ID: 170064036106aa7b54907f1469ee019". There was an error when running the test but localhost still works normally. Is there any solution? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

For 404 and 503 there are content pages available in `Content > Pages` so you can edit that page but 403 error page.

First You also have to add Fastly troubleshooting, if you are adding it till now.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/cdn/trouble-fastly.html

To edit the WAF error page:

1. Log in to the Magento Admin UI.
2. Click Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > System.
3. In the right pane, expand Full Page Cache > Fastly Configuration >
   Custom Synthetic Pages.

[image]

4. Click Edit WAF page.
5. Complete the fields to update the HTML.

[image]

- Status—Select the 403 Forbidden status.
- MIME type—Type text/html.
- Content—Edit the default HTML response to add custom CSS and update
  the title and messaging as needed.

  6. Click Upload at the top of the page to upload the customized HTML source to the Fastly server.
  7. Click Save Config at the top of the page to save the updated configuration file.
  8. Refresh the cache.

     - In the notification at the top of the page, click the Cache Management link.
     - On the Cache Management page, click Flush Magento Cache.

For Reference Magento Documentation: [Customize error pages](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/cdn/cloud-fastly-custom-response.html)

Comment: Hii Full Page Cache > Fastly Configuration > Custom Synthetic Pages. This option not available in admin

Comment: @Parthavi which magento version you are using?

Comment: Magento Version 2.2.5

Comment: Ok if you are using Magento 2 you have to setup Fastly Troubleshooting. Please check this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/cdn/trouble-fastly.html

Comment: Fastly is available only in the Magento Commerce Cloud edition.